# Detecting ordered iterables (sequences) in python

Tags: python

I am attempting to build a function that takes an iterable and returns a tuple, provided that the iterable will always be iterated over in a canonical way.  For example, if the input iterable is `list` or `tuple`-like, I want to accept the input, but not if it is `dict`-like (where there isn't a guarantee on the order of the keys).  Is there any python function to detect the different between objects that are always iterated in the same order vs. those where the order could change version-to-version or depend on `PYTHONHASHSEED`?

`isinstance(x, collections.Sequence)` does most of what I want, but generators are not sequences.  The following code seems to do what I want, but I'm not sure if I'm leaving something out or if there is a more general way to capture the idea of an ordered, but not necessarily indexable, iterable.

```
import collections, types
def to_tuple(x):
    if isinstance(x, collections.Sequence) or isinstance(x, types.GeneratorType):
        return tuple(x)
    raise Exception("Cannot be iterated canonically")
```

Comment: Regarding generators - you can't go over the same generator second time in the same manner - so why would you want to include it?

Comment: @AdamSosnowski If that's an issue, I suppose I could use `itertools.tee()` to clone the generator first, but for my uses, It doesn't matter if I mangle the original input.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such function. Even with generators, you'd want to be able to catch

```
(x for x in {1, 2, 3})
```

but permit

```
(x for x in [1, 2, 3])
```

I'd recommend just raising a warning if `type(x) is dict`. Not even `isinstance(x, dict)`, because OrderedDicts are ordered.

Comment: You'd also have to cut out `set` and other `dict` subclasses.  I'd rather cut out anything that inherits from `collections.Set` or `collections.Mapping` unless it also inherits from `collections.OrderedDict`.  Of course, as you've very well pointed out, it's impossible to get this perfect.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Maybe your subclass is ordered! Even if you special-case `collections.OrderedDict`, maybe you're using Django's old [`SortedDict`](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict), or the `SortedDict` from [SortedContainers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers). I suppose warning on `type(x) in (dict, set, frozenset)` would be an okay extension.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check if slicing operation is defined:

```
def to_tuple(x):
  return tuple(x[:])
```

That rules out dictionaries, generators, but welcomes strings, tuples, lists...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think this is really any better than `isinstance(x, collections.Sequence)` which OP already rejected for not supporting generators.

Comment: Well... it tests behavior in place of inheritance. For example the "Sequence" tests fails for numpy.ndarray and slicing succeeds.

Comment: To play devils advocate -- You're only testing whether the object has a `__getitem__` that accepts a slice.  You aren't testing that it is ordered in any meaningful way.  FWIW, `isinstance(x, collections.SomeABC)` is also pretty much just testing for the existence of certain methods... Yours actually _calls_ the methods, so it's a little better in that respect, but not a whole lot really...